# On the set of points "inside" a closed curve

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

consider the following: one has a simple closed rectifiable curve $\gamma$ in the plane, and there is a point $a$ such that for all $p\in\gamma$ the segment $\overline{ap}$ intersects $\gamma$ only in $p$. Let $G$ be the set of points which are inside $\gamma$, i.e. those points $q$ such that the segment $\overline{aq}$ doesn't intersect $\gamma$. Then one has that $G$ is an open and connected set with boundary equal to $\gamma$.
Up to now I managed to prove openness, connectedness and that $\gamma$ is contained in the boundary. However I am quite clueless about how to prove the reverse inclusion, does somebody have any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Jordan's curve Theorem? If so then, you can prove the remaining inclusion as follows: Take $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \gamma$. By the Jordan's Theorem this set should be disconnected. However, if you assume that there exists a point $x$ in the boundary of $G$ which is not on $\gamma$ then this point (not being in $G$ since $G$ is open) is connected by a segment with $a$, contradicting the disconectedness of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \gamma$.

Comment: No I am not. I suppose one should do it only with point set topology...